# How to GET request if login_required in DJango

Tags: django, api, authentication, get, request

Here my API:

```
@login_required
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_order(request):

    order_list = Order.objects.values("user_name",
                        "user_surname",
                        "order_date").all()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps([x for x in order_list])
```

The problem is when i add `@login_required`, i'm trying to do a Postman GET request using `BASIC authentication` with `username` and `password`.
If i remove the `@login_required`, i can perform a succesful GET request without auth in Postman.

Comment: maybe you can try some one like this: if request.user.is_authenticated: ....do..something...else:.........redirect to your login...

Comment: @Tegito123 That doesn't solve the problem, as that's not how Postman is normally used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, login with your browser. Next, locate where the corresponding authentication cookie is stored in your browser. Copy it to your clipboard. Finally, paste the cookie and pass it along with the GET request in Postman:

[image]

The name of the cookie is `sessionid`.